# Sharepoint Password Compromised

Tags: server-farm, service-account, password

My sharepoint farm user password has been compromised and exposed. I need to change it! is there a simple way to do this?
I'm thinking in change the farm user password and then run after whatever problems appear but that is kinda dangerous and i wont be 100% sure that everything is working fine... I was hoping for a more secure (even if its more dificult to execute) way to do it!
Tks for the support.

Comment: Have a look at this. [Updating passwords on SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2011/01/25/updating-passwords-on-sharepoint-2010.aspx). Never had to resort to this, but I fear your situation is critical, so I'm posting it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because i did a "by the book" installation all i had to do was:

1. Go to Central Admin
2. Go to Secutrity
3. Click Configure Managed Accounts
4. Edit the user you want and edit it
5. Check the box "Change Password Now"
6. Insert new password and Save
7. Celebrate!

Answer (score 0):

You must be very carefull when changing the password of the farm account. Maybe [this](http://www.tsls.co.uk/index.php/2011/01/21/how-to-change-the-farm-service-account-in-sharepoint-2010/) post will help.

Comment: When you add an answer that contains a link, please try to give some details regarding the process described in the article. Even if you leave out some details. Blogs sometimes vanish. I have seen 3 questions on the MSDN forums just today that had only links marked as the answer and all 3 links gave 404 errors. Giving some details ensures your answer will have some utility even if the blog gets moved or deleted.